# Match Everything Except Email With This Regex Pattern

Tags: regex, string, email, pattern-matching

So, I have rows of text with plenty unnecessary information in them (in a google sheet). I would like to match everything except the EMAIL for which I'm using the following regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+(?!png|jpg|gif)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+
```

If I can manage to match everything except the email, then I can just find/replace and leave only the email in the row which is what I want. Having some trouble here. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Regex highly depends on flavor you are using. In which application/ programming language are you intend to use regex? Some regex flavor doesn't support negative lookbehind and so.

Comment: I was going to use javascript, but for now just a simple Google sheet find/replace with the 'search using regular expressions' box checked. If you have other ideas - let me know - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not perfect this could be what you're after:

For the online demo this works: `^(?:.*?(\w[^@\s]*@[^@\s]{2,}).*?|.+)$`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV1iY0/2)

However for Google Sheets you need to remove the `^` and `$` line start/end markers and it should do most of what you want. So:

`(?:.*?(\w[^@\s]*@[^@\s]{2,}).*?|.+)`

replace this pattern with $1 to leave just the email address per line

This works per line, the pattern is made up of two patterns in a non-capturing group `(?:`. First pattern looks from the start of the line `.*?` to lazily match all characters up until group1 containing the email pattern `(\w[^@\s]*@[^@\s]{2,})` followed by anything else `.*` till the end of the line. The second pattern will match all other lines without an email. This is the search pattern. The replace pattern is simply group1 `$1`. Group1 will be empty if no email address is found thus each line will either be blank or be populated with the email address.

This might not match *all* email addresses but should match most. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) for a lengthy read about regex matching email addresses.

Comment: Thanks for this, but as per my original request I'm looking to match everything except for email addresses so that when I can find/replace it is only the emails that are left over. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you check the demo? This does exactly what you're after. What it does is finds everything but marks the email as a group. When doing the replace it fills each line with group 1. Thus leaves only email addresses.

Comment: Thanks for that, close! But this is what happens: 
[gif example of regex](http://goo.gl/ajBe6H)

Comment: Oh right. I hadn't considered how regex works in Google Sheets. You can try $1 instead of \1. I think my pattern might work after some tailoring

Comment: Just did a quick test. `$1` as the replace value works but as I suspected ^ and $ line start/end markers are causing multi-line cells to not match

Comment: I've updated the answer. It was actually as simple as removing the line start/end markers and using $1. The only thing you might want to revise is the email pattern `\w[^@\s]*@[^@\s]{2,}` as I had what look like a few false positives in my test. The linked question should help you with that though.

Comment: Actually, is there anyway to replace everything but only keep one email? Finding a lot of fields with multi-line emails or joined emails and it's messing up a little. (i.e. returning results like so: "
`thewodapalooza,nInfo@thewodapalooza.com,54402966,thewodapalooza,The"`

Comment: Yeah so turns out you can return just one email with `^(?:[\S\s]*?(\w[^@\s]*@[^@\s]{2,})[\S\s]*?|[\S\s]+)$`. For lines like your example you'll need to replace the email pattern. Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/8829363/1015849

Answer (score 0):

You can't match everything but email. But you can match everything *and* email.

Match anything non-greedily followed by captured email or end of string. Change to the capture group, globally:

```
"BLAHBLAHemailBLAHBLAHemailBLAH".replace(/.*?(email|$)/g, "$1");
// => "emailemail"
```

(insert your own email regexp.)